# local to UTC conversion in java

Tags: java, timezone, utc

I need to convert local time at a specific city to UTC.

For example , 
convert time in NYC to UTC .

If I pass the local time and country , the service should be able to return the UTC

Is there  any library/utility which maps the city/country to timezone and then converts it to UTC ?

I am trying to avoid building a time zone master and do the conversion .

Since this is common problem, if there are any libraries which are already doing it - please revert back

Answer (score 0):

Just need to use Calendar and TimeZone classes?

Define a TimeZone for UTC:

> TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");

And then create the calendar

> Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(tz);

To retrieve the Date object use calendar.getTime

> cal.getTime()

If you already have your date in a Date object (localDate) you can use a formatter:

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(); formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); 
String dateinUTC = formatter.format(localDate)

Comment: i have clarified my question . I need UTC based on local time of a city

Comment: If you have the local time stored in a Date object (localDate) you can use a formatter:

  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat();
  formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String dateinUTC = formatter.format(localDate);

I'll update the answer